# I cant get gitHub actions to publish my package build to nuget.pkg.github

Tags: github, github-actions

I have been trying for a few months now, just to get GitHub actions to push a build to the gitHub packages, everytime i come back, try something else, nothing seems to work and it isnt making any sense.

I have just seen a new link with more details added for gitActions here:

[image]

I got excited, clicked, and see more code than previous had:

```
// Step 1: Authenticate (if this is the first time) Note you must also pass --store-password-in-clear-text on non-Windows systems.
$ dotnet nuget add source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/xxxxx/index.json -n github -u xxxxx -p GH_TOKEN [--store-password-in-clear-text]
// Step 2: Pack
$ dotnet pack --configuration Release
// Step 3: Publish
$ dotnet nuget push "bin/Release/myproject.1.0.0.nupkg" --source "github"
```

so, i went to my yml page (all within GitHub) and noticed the format is a little different... they are missing the "- name: xxx"  and "run: xxx"

so, i updated... here is my full yml

```
name: .NET Core

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.101
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal
    - name: nuGet publish
      run: dotnet nuget add source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/xxxx/index.json -n github -u xxxx-p GH_TOKEN [--store-password-in-clear-text]
    - name: nuGet pack
      run: dotnet pack --configuration Release
    - name: publish
      run: dotnet nuget push "bin/Release/projectname.1.0.0.nupkg" --source "github"
```

now, i thought maybe it would complain about password or something, but instead, im just getting this error: (i.e. "error: Unrecognized command or argument 'add'")

[image]

I am at a total loss and have no idea what and how to do this.... it builds fine all in gitHub, my package location is in GitHub, what am i doing so wrong?

EDIT:
thank you @ColinM after adjusting the yml above and just changin the version to 3.1.200, it now gets further, however, getting the following

```
Password encryption is not supported on .NET Core for this platform. The following feed try to use an encrypted password: 'github'. You can use a clear text password as a workaround
```

when running this line

```
Run dotnet nuget add source nuget.pkg.github.com/myname/index.json -n github -u myname -p abc123"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the MSDN documentation for [dotnet nuget source add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-add-source), this is available only from SDK 3.1.200 onwards; whereas you're currently using 3.1.101.

Update your YAML file to install an SDK version equal to or greater than 3.1.200

Comment: Thanks, getting this now: Password encryption is not supported on .NET Core for this platform. The following feed try to use an encrypted password: 'github'. You can use a clear text password as a workaround. when the run line is: "Run dotnet nuget add source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myname/index.json -n github -u myname -p abc123"

Comment: That's sounds like a different problem, as such I'd recommend posting a new question for this. It will certainly help somebody else in the future if coming across either of these issues.

Comment: will do... ill do some searching first (not much luck yet), will update my question if i find the answer or post a new question.  Thank you, have marked your answer as the answer :)