# Incorrect Path and No API errors when trying to publish to GitHub packages via GitHubActions

Tags: github, github-actions

been stuck on this for a long time now, seems to be one problem after the other, just trying to get GitHub Actions to publish a nuGet package to GitHub packages, documentations is really hard to find and doesnt seem to give any clear examples

This was my previous question (just for context incase it helps)
[I cant get gitHub actions to publish my package build to nuget.pkg.github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63309348/i-cant-get-github-actions-to-publish-my-package-build-to-nuget-pkg-github)

but now, I am getting the following:

```
Run dotnet nuget push "bin/Release/Project.1.0.0.nupkg" --source "github"
warn : No API Key was provided and no API Key could be found for 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/name'. To save an API Key for a source use the 'setApiKey' command.
error: Could not find a part of the path '/home/runner/work/project/project/bin/Release'.
```

Here is my full yml

```
name: .NET Core

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.200
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal
    - name: nuGet publish
      run: dotnet nuget add source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/name/index.json -n github -u uname -p password123 --store-password-in-clear-text
    - name: nuGet pack
      run: dotnet pack --configuration Release
    - name: publish
      run: dotnet nuget push "bin/Release/EurekaShared.1.0.0.nupkg" --source "github"
```

this is the build result:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `dotnet nuget push "bin/Release/EurekaShared.1.0.0.nupkg" --source "github" -k "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"`? (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-push)

Comment: Seems like the `.nupkg` file is not where you expect it to be. Can you please add the output log of the build and pack steps to your question.

Answer (score 0):

`dotnet nuget` sadly doesn't always work as expected, and also has a habit of returning misleading error messages. It's infuriating.

Try adding a [`nuget/setup-nuget@v1`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-nuget-exe-for-use-with-actions) step to your workflow and use `nuget.exe push` instead of `dotnet nuget push`. That might either fix the problem or at least give you a more helpful error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is related with the **part of the path** to `nupkg` file, or file name. It could be issue of case, since Linux is case-sensitive.

Moreover, this workflow file is to publish just one package, i.e., `EurekaShared.1.0.0.nupkg` it won't work if your package is `EurekaShared.1.0.2.nupkg`

Perhaps you can give it a try by updating the last line in your YML file by using wildcard ** as follows:

```
run: dotnet nuget push /**/*.nupkg --source "github"
```

I also suggest that you secure your username and password in workflow file with GitHub encrypted secrets https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets